# Bind IsEnabled to linq property with linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, mvvm, binding

i would like to bind in XAML button's attribute "IsEnabled" to the condition, like "enable button only if all of items in my Observable collection have IsValid property = true". So the Linq expression would look like:

```
MyObsCollectionProp.Any(record=>!record.IsValid)
```

or

```
 MyObsCollectionProp.All(record=>record.IsValid)
```

Can sombody tell my the legal and valid (for MVVM pattern) way to do this?

Comment: return that as a property in the model ?

Comment: @Aybe, yeah, but in a viewModel, not model,and bind it to IsEnabled attribute in xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a boolean property named IsButtonEnable as:

```
private bool isButtonEnable;
public bool IsButtonEnable
{
    get
    {
        return isButtonEnable;
    }
    set
    {
        isButtonEnable = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsButtonEnable");
    }
}
```

Bind a button with this property as:

```
<Button Content="Save Data" IsEnable="{Binding IsButtonEnable, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Button>
```

Now in your ViewModel bind ObservableCollectionChanged event as:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    MyObsCollectionProp = new ObservableCollection<YourModel>();
    MyObsCollectionProp += MyObsCollectionProp_Changed;
}
void MyObsCollectionProp_Changed(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle here
    IsButtonEnable = MyObsCollectionProp.All(record=>record.IsValid)
}
```

Comment: I've been doing WPF on and off for ~8 years and never knew that ObservableCollection-changed event was a thing. Thanks!